# Cache not found for input keys in GitHub Actions for docker images

Tags: docker, github, yaml

I'm trying to cache the base docker images to improve my build time and reduce network overhead.

This is part of my action YAML

```
      - name: Cache Docker
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: |
            /var/lib/docker/image
          key: docker-layers-${{ runner.os }}-pull-image

      - name: Pull images
        run: |
          docker pull holism/panel
          docker pull node:lts-bookworm-slim
```

As you can see, I use
actions/cache@v4
and provide a cache key. And then pull the images from the Docker Hub.

However, in subsequent action runs, I get this message for
Cache Docker
step:

> Cache not found for input keys: docker-layers-Linux-pull-image

What can be wrong here? Is it not enough to specify a key for caching docker images?